# Create Dockerfile to deploy NestJS API to fly.io

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nestjs, fly

I created a REST API using NestJS and I want to deploy it to fly.io. fly.io requires me to create a `Dockerfile` to do so. I don't know much about `Dockerfile`s but fly.io has a cli tool that creates one for you.

I am not able to deploy my API, however, and my suspicion is that there's an issue with the `Dockerfile`. Specifically, that the generated `Dockerfile` isn't tailored specifically to a NESTJS app.

I am linking my repo below so you can view both the existing `Dockerfile` and the structure of my API. Can someone please suggest how I can modify the `Dockerfile` to work for a NESTJS app?

Thanks

https://github.com/AhmedAbbasDeveloper/noteify-server/tree/nestjs-migration

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose a port that your nestjs server runs on. For your docker image you can set an env variable by adding `ENV PORT=8080` to your `Dockerfile` and also need to expose it with `EXPOSE 8080`. You can use any port, but since you've configured 8080 in fly, that makes more sense.

```
...
ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This dockerfile worked for me.

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

ENV NODE_ENV build

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN npm run build \
    && npm prune --production

# ---

FROM node:16-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /home/node/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /home/node/node_modules/ ./node_modules/
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /home/node/dist/ ./dist/

CMD ["node", "dist/server.js"]
```